# Syncfusion SfButton click animation is not working in Android and iOS devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

SfButton ControlTemplate initialization is not showing the button pressed animation in Android and iOS devices.

I am having a Xamarin.Forms app and I am using the SyncFusion button inside the ControlTemplate for displaying the button with Grid columns. When I am pressing this button from the UWP app it is showing the button click animation but when I am using it from Android/iOS the click event is triggering but the Button click animation is not there.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonWithStripTemplate">
    <sfButton:SfButton CornerRadius="4" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}" BorderWidth="0" Margin="3"
        Command="{TemplateBinding Command}" CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}"
        AutomationId="{TemplateBinding ContentTitle}">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="16,*" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding StripBackgroundColor}">
                <Label Text="{TemplateBinding StripText}" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Label Text="{TemplateBinding ContentTitle}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeMedium}" Margin="8,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <BoxView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Gray">
                <BoxView.Opacity>
                    <Binding Path="IsEnabled" Source="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <converters:BoolToObjectConverter x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                TrueObj="0"
                                FalseObj="0.7"/>
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </BoxView.Opacity>
            </BoxView>
        </Grid>
    </sfButton:SfButton>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This is the ControlTemplate code and I am fetching this from the ControlTemplate option.
Can anyone help me for finding the root cause of why the animation is not showing on Android/iOS devices?